# how to get the desired vertical list in python?

Tags: python

how to read a file vertically? So for instance a file would contain the following:

```
1234
4567
7890
```

to obtain `[147, 258, 369 479]`

this was used

```
rows = [line.split() for line in f]

columns=zip(*rows)
print(columns)
```

and the following was obtained

```
zip object
```

what should i do to fix it? so that i get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Python 3, where `zip` returns an iterator. To see the values, you need to consume the iterator, e.g. using the `list` constructor:

```
columns = list(zip(*rows))
```

To obtain individual columns in individual variables, you can unpack them:

```
col1, col2, ... = zip(*rows)
```

If the file really has only a single column, there is no reason to call `split` in the first place. Simply read the lines into a list:

```
col = [int(line) for line in f]     # or float(line)...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 `zip` returns a `zip` object, useful for iterating over but not so much for printing. The fix is easy though:

```
print(list(columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code

```py
lines = "1234 4567 7890"
rows_iter = [iter(s) for s in lines.split()]
cols_as_list = zip(*strs_iter)
cols = [''.join(c) for c in cols_as_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data in a file called 'foop.txt', here you go:

```
z = zip(*(l for l in open('foop.txt')))
columns = [''.join(x) for x in z]
print columns
```

results in:

```
['147', '258', '369', '470']
```

If you want to leave 'columns' as a generator one would just change that line:

```
columns = (''.join(x) for x in z)
```